# can't export htmltable to xls file when using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, export, xls

I need to export a htmltable to xls,

I have a page that uses jquery heavily and has a link triggers a jquery post

```
 var downloadType = document.getElementById("downloadType");         
 var downloadTypeValue = downloadType.options[downloadType.selectedIndex].value;
 var data = {
     exportFormat: downloadTypeValue               
 };
 $.post("ajax.aspx",data);
```

as you can see, the link post file format to a page named ajax.aspx which runs the following code

```
 HtmlTable tableToExport = (HtmlTable)Session["tblReportResult"];
 StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
 tableToExport.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=wateva.xls");
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
 Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
 Response.End();
```

so it retrieves the htmltable control from the session and use response.write to generate the file, however, it's not working...any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using iframe to return the file that works great!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is javascript which is front-end.  If all you're passing to the backend is a format, there is no possible way you can export on the backend what is stored only on the frontend.

Comment: the data to export is stored in Session["tblReportResult"] i just need the user to choose which format they want.

Comment: So you're trying to return a file from an AJAX request?  And what is the point of passing `exportFormat`, I don't see you using it.

Comment: thanks for replaying, exportFormat can be valued as csv, xls, and docx, the user click on the link to pass the value so that I can export the file in demanded format. it's not used because atm I'm just experimenting on xls as you can see in Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=wateva.xls");

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you cannot return files from an ajax request.  I could be wrong, but I've never seen it.

Comment: I think you're right kingjiv, I might have to figure out another approach.